# Default Printer causing printing issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, network-printer, crystalreports

I apologize if this is not the place for this question, please let me know.

We are running a Windows Server domain with multiple networked printers.  Some of our label printers will change their margins/print size magically when a certain printer is selected.

I have isolated it to a Canon iR2525 printer, when set as default, that causes this problem.  For example, when printing a 4x8 label to a Zebra LP2844 printer, it works fine with any printer selected as the default other than the Canon iR2525.  When the Canon is set as the default, the labels think they are larger sized (say 5x10 or so), so the page footer does not print on the label.

Has anyone else had issues like this before?  I am not sure why it happens only when the Canon iR2525 is set as the default.  It is not only happening with the Zebra printer, there are a couple other Cognitive and Datamax printers that have the same problem.

If this is not the correct place for this question, please point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:**

The labels are printed using Crystal Reports, so that may be part of the cause as well.  We have just been dealing with this for the last few years by trying to ensure that the Canon printer isn't set as default, but the problem is that some of the software we use sets the default printer when you print, rather than just printing to the selected printer.

Comment: You mentioned a Windows Server. Are the printers served VIA the server?

Comment: No, the printers are all TCP/IP networked printers.  I just mentioned Windows Server so that people would know my environment.

Comment: Does deselecting the Canon fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the question, when the Canon is not set as the default printer, the problem does not occur.  The strange thing is, the labels are being printed to the same Zebra/Cognitive/Datamax printers regardless of which printer is set as the default.  But for some reason, having the Canon set as default causes problems.  I should also mention that the labels are printed using Crystal Reports, so that could play into the issue.  I will update the question to include that information.